# Parse an XML file from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file, I need to be able to pass a single parameter to a batch file "DEV2_BUSINESSAPPS_URL", if found I want the "https://energy.epipelines.com/businessapps/welcome.html" returned. Unfortunately it has to be a batch file.

Here is my XML file:

```
 <Environment>
             <Variable>
                   <Name>DEV1_BUSINESSAPPS_URL</Name>
                   <Value><![CDATA[https://energy.epipelines.com/businessapps/welcome.html]]></Value>
             </Variable>
             <Variable>
                   <Name>DEV2_BUSINESSAPPS_URL</Name>
                   <Value><![CDATA[https://energy.epipelines.com/businessapps/welcome.html]]></Value>
             </Variable>
             <Variable>
                   <Name>DEV3_BUSINESSAPPS_URL</Name>
                   <Value><![CDATA[https://energy.epipelines.com/businessapps/welcome.html]]></Value>
             </Variable>
             <Variable>
                   <Name>QA1_BUSINESSAPPS_URL</Name>
                   <Value><![CDATA[https://qa1comapps.elm.com/businessapps]]></Value>
             </Variable>
 </Environment>
```

Comment: Working with markup (especially with those angle brackets) is no fun in Batch. Can you use a third-party exe or perhaps use Batch to create and execute a temporary script in the scripting host or powershell? Or does it have to be 100% batch implementation only?

Comment: You would be better off using VBscript, Jscript or powershell as these languages have objects to natively parse XML.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please regard that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also the help topic [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. It's pretty brittle because it's not easy to make Batch understand differences in markup file layout that can vary like in XML. But, as long as the file is in the format you've specified, this should work.

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=^<^>![] " %%a in (file.xml) do (
    if defined nextline echo %%c&set nextline=
    if "%%a"=="Name" if "%%b"=="%~1" set nextline=1
)
```

Output of `test.cmd DEV2_BUSINESSAPPS_URL`:
`https://energy.epipelines.com/businessapps/welcome.html`

Obviously, change the file names accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat)  -small script that will allow you to get a xml  values by xpath expression without using external binaries:

```
call xpath.bat "environment.xml" "//Variable[Name = 'DEV1_BUSINESSAPPS_URL']/Value"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would probably do what you want (see the explanatory `rem` remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1"   & rem // (use first command line argument as target XML file)
set "_FIND=%~2"   & rem // (use second command line argument as a name to find)
set "_TAG1=Name"  & rem // (name of the tag expected in the 1st line of a pair)
set "_TAG2=Value" & rem // (name of the tag expected in the 2nd line of a pair)

rem // Store the name to find in a `for` variable:
for /F "delims= eol=<" %%K in ("%_FIND%") do (
    rem // Loop through lines of target XML file, ignore leading white-spaces:
    set "PREV=#" & for /F "usebackq tokens=* eol= " %%L in ("%_FILE%") do (
        rem // Store current line in variable:
        set "LINE=%%L" & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Check whether previous line contains 1st tag and name to find:
        if not "!PREV!" == "!PREV:<Name>%%K</Name>=!" (
            rem // Check whether current line contains 2nd tag (around the URL):
            set "TEST=!LINE:*<Value>=!"
            if not "!LINE!" == "!TEST!" if not "!TEST!" == "!TEST:</Value>=!" (
                rem // Remove prefix and suffix from URL to extract:
                set "TEST=!TEST:*<![CDATA[=|!"
                for /F "delims=| eol=|" %%U in ("!TEST:]]>=|!") do (
                    rem // Actually return the desired URL:
                    endlocal & echo(%%U
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                )
            )
        )
        rem // Store current line in variable for the next loop iteration:
        endlocal & set "PREV=%%L"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```